# Typescript - auto conversion from a Json string with a date string to an object with a Date property

Tags: json, typescript, rest

When calling a REST service returning JSON, how can I format a date so that it is converted automatically into a typescript Date object?

The result of calling a REST call is this message:

> {"id":3796,...,"startTempValue":"2019-05-26T19:39:01Z"}

I also tried this ISO format:

> {"id":3796,...,"startTempValue": "2019-05-26T19:39:01.000Z"}

The model object is:

```
export class Settings {
    public id: number;
    public shortName;
    public description: string;
    public value: string;
    public possibleValues: string;
    public startTempValue: Date;
}
```

The result of startTempValue is a string ... ?! I want the startTempValue to be a Date object.

Of course, I could convert the Date string to a Date object manually. So, doing something like the code below at reception of the REST service result. **But there should be a better way.** Another alternative would be to convert it at the server to an epoch (milliconds). That is possible, but still, this 'string' variant is more readable.

```
if ( this.settings[i].startTempValue !== undefined && 
     this.settings[i].startTempValue !== null) {
    this.settings[i].startTempValue = new Date(this.settings[i].startTempValue);
} else {
    this.settings[i].startTempValue = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON only deals with primitives like numbers, strings, arrays and objects.

There is no information within JSON that describes what its contents mean. So even if something looks like a date to you, it's still just a string.

So how could you convert it manually? Well, if you know in advanced what property names are *always* dates, you could loop through the result and convert these preemptively. Or you could loop through all the values and take anything that *looks* like a date and automatically convert.

A third option would be to have some kind of schema that marks certain things as dates and use that for your automatic conversion.

The point is that there is no built-in way to infer this, and it's kind of up to you do to something else with your data